# Ошибка среды разработки

Tags: node.js, phpstorm, typescript, socket.io

[image: ошибка]

Компилируется и работает нормально, но почему IDE жалуется?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что вы импортируете **socketIo**, а обращаетесь к **SocketIO**

Comment: но все же работает правильно

Comment: @ДенисПодоляченко Это уже другой вопрос - почему у вас при этом всё работает